# .replace not working in beautiful soup

Tags: python, replace, beautifulsoup

This is just a part of the code. It is not replacing the values of div and a href. It is a beautiful soup class tag

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(ourUrl)
dem = soup.findAll('p')
for i in range(0,len(dem)-1):
              dk = dem[i]


              if ('<div') in dk:
                   print "it here"
                   dk =dk.replace('<div','<!--')
                   dk =dk.replace('</div>','--->')
                   dem[i] = dk
for i in range(0,len(dem)-1):
              dk = dem[i]
              if ('<a href') in dk:
                   print "it here"
                   dk =dk.replace('<a href','<!--')
                   dk =dk.replace('</a>','--->')
                   dem[i] = dk
```

dem value is somthing like:

```
dem =[    <p class="left-text padding-left-10">
<a href="/people" class="red-text">See all people</a>
</p>
<p class="left-text padding-left-10">
<a href="/tv" class="red-text" style="display:inline;">See all bio TV</a>
<span class="divider">&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
<a href="/tv/daily-schedule" class="red-text" style="display:inline;">See schedule </a>
</p>
<p class="left-text bottom-flyout-video-padding">
<a href="/videos" class="red-text ">See all videos</a>
</p>
<p class="left-text padding-left-10">
<a href="http://shop.history.com/?v=biography" class="red-text">Shop now</a>
</p>
<p>TV14 </p>
<p>He rose from the slums of Brooklyn to take on the biggest Mafia dons of the 1950s and 1960s. Joey Gallo began his criminal career as a small-time loan shark and jukebox racketeer. He became a top enforcer in the Profaci crime family, but felt he never got the respect he deserved. So Gallo formed his own gang and revolted against mafia Don Joe Profaci in a long, bloody war on the streets of New York. But there was another side to Joey Gallo--the ruthless mob leader was also an artist and an avid reader. Living in Greenwich Village with his wife Jeffie, Gallo was inspired by his beatnik neighbors and their counterculture ideas. He also began hobnobbing with New York's social elite, befriending everyone from Neil Simon to Jerry Orbach. In the end though, nothing could save Joey Gallo from a dramatic end.</p>
<p>TV14 </p>
<p>
<p> Charles Darwin, <a href="/people/charles-darwin-9266433">http://www.biography.com/people/charles-darwin-9266433</a> (last visited Aug 27, 2013).</p>
<p> Charles Darwin. The Biography Channel website. 2013. Available at: <a href="/people/charles-darwin-9266433">http://www.biography.com/people/charles-darwin-9266433</a>. Accessed Aug 27, 2013. </p>
<p>Naturalist Charles Darwin was born in Shrewsbury, England, on February 12, 1809. In 1831, he embarked on a five-year survey voyage around the world on the HMS <i>Beagle</i>. His studies of specimens around the globe led him to formulate his theory of evolution and his views on the process of natural selection. In 1859, he published <i>On the Origin of Species</i>. He died on April 19, 1882, in London.</p>
<p><span class="body">A man who dares to waste one hour of time has not discovered the value of life.</span></p>


                            571 people in this group<br />
</p>]
```

The dem value is too large to enter, so i've given you an extract. Even though there is

Comment: There is *no* `.replace()` method in on BeautifulSoup elements.

Comment: BeautifulSoup elements are *not* strings; did you want to comment out the `<div>` elements or just remove them altogether?

Comment: Note that there are **no** `div` tags anywhere in your paragraphs, so that part of the code has nothing to replace in any case.

Comment: that's fine but there are some paras with div and even for those it's not working

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to replace elements with a comment containing the replaced tag, replace the object with a new `bs4.Comment()` object:

```
from bs4 import Comment

for para in soup.find_all('p'):
    for div in para.find_all('div'):
        div.replace_with(Comment(unicode(div)))
    for link in para.find_all('a', href=True):
        link.replace_with(Comment(unicode(link)))
```

In Python, instead of using a `for` loop with `range()`, just loop over the sequence *directly*; in the above code I loop directly over the `.find_all()` results.

BeautifulSoup elements may print as if they are just HTML text, but in reality they are not strings but [`Tag()` objects](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#tag). Don't try to treat them as strings.

Comment: are you sure its find_all cause it returns an error. Only on changing to findall it enters the loop. Same with replacewith

Comment: @user2707082: I assumed BeautifulSoup 4 here; if you are still using BeautifulSoup version 3, then the methods are called `.findAll()` and `.replaceWith()`, and the import would be `from BeautifulSoup import Comment`.

Comment: I tested the code again, it works as advertised. And it it definitely [`.find_all()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) and [`.replace_with()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#replace-with) so something else is wrong.